# Infragistics designer changes code behind

Tags: c#, infragistics

I have used both windows and Infragistics controls on a Windows form few years back. Now, i want to add a new button(windows control) on that form but it changes the code behind. All of the Infragistics controls are removed as soon as I add a button to that form.

Comment: Does anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Comment: Is this a WinForms application? What version of Infragistics and .NET Framework are you using? Also, are you programmatically adding the IG controls in the code behind and that code is removed?

Comment: Yes this is winform.I am using .Net4 and infragistics v10.1.Yes infragistcs code was added in code behind programmatically and it was removed.@Zairja

Comment: That's very strange. Are you adding the Windows control via code behind, as well, or through the designer?

Comment: windows controls were added few years back through designer.Now i want to window control @Zairja